# How to use exports.up method?

Tags: node.js

What does exports.up do? How can I use this method?
I searched but I can't find any documentation for this.

```
exports.up = function(db) {
    :
    :
   return Promise.resolve('resolve');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

These are sequelize migration methods as you can find [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html) in the documentation. This is a migration skeleton from the sequelize docs

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    // logic for transforming into the new state
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    // logic for reverting the changes
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a general convention used in SQL migrations. Migrations here being very misleading if you are familiar with the term anywhere else.

Here a migration means making some change to a database. However, things like Sequelize will instead record that change to a file such that the change can be reverted if desired.

From [the documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/):

> A Migration in Sequelize is a javascript file which exports two
> functions, up and down, that dictates how to perform the migration and
> undo it. You define those functions manually, but you don't call them
> manually; they will be called automatically by the CLI. In these
> functions, you should simply perform whatever queries you need, with
> the help of sequelize.query and whichever other methods Sequelize
> provides to you. There is no extra magic beyond that.

Realize that the up/down functions are conventions. I'm using [knex](https://knexjs.org/) and it has the same convention/functionality. You start with the functions as you mentioned:

```js
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {

};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {

};
```

The up function will make the change to the database. Usually up will contain a bunch of stuff from your schema building program. The other function, down, reverts those changes. This allows you to quickly revert a change if you need to. Here is a snippit of some code I'm working on:

```js
exports.up = async (knex) => {
    return await Promise.all([
      ...SNIP...
      knex.schema.createTable('user_uploads', function (table) {
        table.increments()
        table
          .string('user')
          .notNullable()
          .references('name')
          .inTable('users')
          .onDelete('CASCADE')
        table
          .string('system_id')
          .notNullable()
          .references('system_id')
          .inTable('systems')
          .onDelete('CASCADE')
        table.string('document_name').notNullable()
        table.string('path').notNullable()
        table.timestamps(undefined, true)
      }),
    ])
}
```

```js
exports.down = function (knex) {
  return Promise.all([
    knex.schema.dropTable('user_roles'),
  ])
}
```